# Como fazer data de entrada e data de saida em c#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, datetime

Boa noite, estou com um projeto na escola de uma Locadora de Veículos. Possuo uma classe que se chama locadora

```
using System;
class Locadora {
  public int IdLocacao {get;set;}
  public int IdCliente{get;set;}
  public int IdCarro{get;set;}
  public override string ToString() {
    return $"ID da Locação {IdLocacao} - Id do Cliente {IdCliente} \n ID do Veículo{IdCarro}";
  }
}
```

com essas informações gostaria de saber como registrar a data de saida do veiculo e a devolução do mesmo. Li alguns artigos em outros fórum porém nao consegui compreender muito bem. No caso eu já imagino que eu usaria um DateTime. Só não sei como implementar...

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: *"já imagino que eu usaria um DateTime. Só não sei como implementar"* só criar uma property como as outras `DateTime Entrada { get; set; }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu caso como mencionado colocaria 2 DateTime salvando a data de locação e a data de devolução do veiculo.

Modificando seu código para:

```
using System;
class Locadora {
  public int IdLocacao {get;set;}
  public int IdCliente{get;set;}
  public int IdCarro{get;set;}
  public DateTime DataLocacao{get;set;}
  public DateTime DataDevolucao{get;set;}
  public override string ToString() {
    return $"ID da Locação {IdLocacao} - Id do Cliente {IdCliente} \n ID do Veículo{IdCarro}";
  }
}
```

Para alimentar o mesmo, nas funções de locação e entrega do veiculo basta colocar

```
Locadora l = new();
l.DataLocacao = DateTime.Now;
```

Caso queira acrescentar na string pode fazer da seguinte forma.

```
public override string ToString() {
        return $"ID da Locação {IdLocacao} - Id do Cliente {IdCliente} \n ID do Veículo{IdCarro} \n Data da Locação {DataLocacao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}  \n Data da Devolução {DataDevolucao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}";
      }
```